# Data migration tool auto add prefix

Tags: magento2.3, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

When I launch data migration tool, I encounter the following error : 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '**`m1.prefix_core_directory_storage`**' doesn't exist ...

My old magento don't use any prefix and y configure my config.xml like this :

what can I do for DMT stop adding prefix and find my table ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Once you are migrating from m1 to m2, there are 2 options:**

1. Source Prefix -  Magento 1 Instance from where data we have to migrate
2. Destination Prefix - Magento 2 Instance where we have to migrate our data

This Migration tools deals with two tags in **config.xml** File: ,

You need to setup in both the places as '' or NULL or remove this parameters from both side that will help you to **Not apply prefix**.